# Include directory for other packages

Tags: ros, include, headers, dependencies

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to learn how to use a package that depends on another package I have created. Both are under ros_workspace/  and one of them(first_pack) depends on the other (lib_test, which is a shared library).

I'm able to compile lib_test, and its header file is located under lib_test/include .
I added  in first_pack's manifest, and included the file "lib_test/mylib.h" in its executable. But when I try to compile it, it shows:

fatal error: lib_test/mylib.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.

I tried adding:

to lib_test manifest, but it still doesn't work. What is the right way to do it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/30425/include-directory-for-other-packages/) by [lgb](https://answers.ros.org/users/2048/lgb/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2012-03-25

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Put your header files of `lib_test` in the directory `lib_test/include/lib_test/`. This directory is automatically exported. You should be able to include `"lib_test/mylib.h"` then in any package that defines the `<depend ...>` in its manifest.

To look for missing include and linking errors, you can use

```
make VERBOSE=1
```

to see the actual compiler command with all the includes that are defined.

---

Originally posted by [Stephan](https://answers.ros.org/users/266/stephan/) with karma: 1924 on 2012-03-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2